# Error en la inicialización del sistema de configuración App de consola

Tags: c#, xml

Tengo el siguiente codigo en una app de consola que instancia una clase y se le asignan valores a sus propiedades

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        objPrdAccess facElec = new objPrdAccess
        {
            UsrPrd = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["usr"].ToString(),
            PwdPrd = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Pwd"].ToString(),
            ArchivoFac = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileDirectory"].ToString()
        };
        .
        .
        .// de mas codigo
    }
}
```

**Actualización**
como está el xml del app.
y el app.config se encuentra de esta forma:

```html
       <configuration>
       //***other stuff
        <applicationSettings>
         <add key="usr" value="adse33324" />
         <add key="Pwd" value="789466" />
         <add key="FileDirectory" value="C:\temp\dsfeerr.zip" />
        </applicationSettings>
     </configuration>
```

al ejecutar el programa me sale el mencionado error **Error en la inicialización del sistema de configuración** Alguna sugerencia para corregirlo?

Comment: en la seccion applicationSettings no veo ninguna key de nombre "usr", ni tampoco "Pwd", cuando quiers leerlo va a fallar sino lo validas. La unica que existe es "FileDirectory" pero debes definir tambien las otras

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Si tenias razón de hecho se me fueron datos que no debían estar en el archivo xml para ejemplificar en esta pregunta; gracias leandro

Comment: Podrias mostrar el error completo que sale?

Comment: @gbianchi  Error en la inicialización del sistema de configuración 
---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 
Sección de configuración no reconocida applicationSettings/add. este es el error completo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La seccion que defines no es valida para el `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` deberias usar

```
<configuration>  
    <appSettings>  
        <add key="usr" value="adse33324" />
        <add key="Pwd" value="789466" />
        <add key="FileDirectory" value="C:\temp\dsfeerr.zip" />
    </appSettings>  
</configuration>
```

como veras la seccion se llama `<appSettings>`

[Four Ways To Read Configuration Setting In C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/four-ways-to-read-configuration-setting-in-c-sharp/)

Si necesitas una seccion distinta entonces deberas usar el

```
var applicationSettings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("ApplicationSettings") as NameValueCollection;
var usr = applicationSettings["usr"];
```

Entonces si aplicara la nueva seccion que definas

```
<configuration>  
   <configSections>  
    <section name="ApplicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>      
  </configSections>  

  <ApplicationSettings>  
         <add key="usr" value="adse33324" />
         <add key="Pwd" value="789466" />
         <add key="FileDirectory" value="C:\temp\dsfeerr.zip" />
  </ApplicationSettings>  

</configuration>
```

Comment: Tutini al parecer era eso la solución, pero ya me sale error en la linea donde inicia el tag <AppSettings>

Comment: no entendi, que es eso de la linea donde inicia el tag ?

Comment: respondi en el foro de msdn https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/d497bc69-7e4c-495e-abba-d9bcb62bbe2e/error-en-la-inicializacin-del-sistema-de-configuracin?forum=vcses